# creating url shortner inside wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to make short url or even pretty URLs inside my wordpress. suppose, i have a the_content filter that finds all external links inside post content, it needs to return short or pretty urls relative to my site URL.

external url:

> stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

pretty url:

> myblog.com/xyxd

making url is not a big deal! but I don't understand how can I then redirects visitors to original external site when he/she is visiting this pretty url?

suppose, one clicks or or enter:

> myblog.com/xyxd

now, I need to redirect him (301/302) to:

> stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

how can I do handle this (and also without conflicting with wordpress's native post/page urls).

any help?

thanks in advance even if you read this problem :).

Note: I had to remove http:// from all links as stackoverflow is not allowing me to put more than one link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [WordPress pretty link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pretty-link/).

UPDATE:

You could hook into `wp_insert_post` and scan the content for URLs using regex or a HTML parser.

Then use the [Pretty Link API](http://blairwilliams.com/pretty-link/api/) to insert pretty links for each URL.

Comment: sir, i have already test that. that is for manual entries. I need to do it programatically! 

thanks for your input

Comment: Thanks. once I thought I can use these functions! later thought no! but as they are suggesting it officially, i believe I can use it :). 

thanks again for link.

Answer (score 0):

You already have one by default

```
http://yourweb.local/blog/?p=2365
```

You can use post IDs as shorturl, something like default settings for permalink structure
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

So inside loop You can use:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('url');?>?p=<?php the_ID(); ?></a>
```

(EDITED:or even better) but don't use: Because moving WP brog to another blog, will leave old blog's address

```
<a href="<?php the_guid(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_guid(); ?></a>
```